# Choosing arbitrary events in probability

Tags: probability, terminology

The question says to "let A, B, and C be arbitrary events in S." I know arbitrary means I can assign any value to it, but when choosing values for events A, B, and C can they be the same or do they have to be different values, since I'm assuming A, B, and C are different values because they're different letters?

Answer (score 1):

They might be equal. In mathematics, statements like "let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers" don't require $x ≠ y$. The hypothesis that $x ≠ y$, if needed, would be mentioned separately, or one would say instead "let $x$ and $y$ be distinct real numbers" or something like that.